# how to get input in a specific order from a file in python

Tags: python, file, input, testcase

I have a file containing many test cases and I want to take them as my inputs, 
the container of the file is like this

```
1 232 4343
2 343 5454
3 545 6556
...
```

I want to have a list of maps so the input will be saved like this:

```
[[232,4343], [343, 5454], [545,6556] , ...]
```

the first input(the number of rows) is easy to get,  just by using the list index of the list but how can I get my other inputs and save them into a list of lists?
I'm using python 3.6.5

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    l=[list(map(int,i.rstrip().split()[1:])) for i in f]
```

And now:

```
print(l)
```

Is:

```
[[232,4343], [343, 5454], [545,6556]]
```

Or faster use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\s+',header=None,index_col=0)
print(df.values.tolist())
```

Output:

```
[[232, 4343], [343, 5454], [545, 6556]]
```

## Update:

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    l=[list(map(int,i.rstrip().split())) for i in f]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 232, 4343], [2, 343, 5454], [3, 545, 6556]]
```

Or with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\s+',header=None)
print(df.values.tolist())
```

*Doing that takes less code...*

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Done!

Comment: @pgh Happy to help, :-), , please accept if it works :-)

Comment: what if i want my index to be in the list too, like [[1,232,4343] , [2,343,5454] ,....]. i tried to modify the code but i wasn't successful modifying it. i would be glad if you could help me